# Intel DAAL library compatible with KNC?

Tags: intel, xeon-phi, intel-dal

I am looking for a definitive answer as to whether the Intel DAAL libraries are compatible with the x100 Knights Corner Xeon Phi co-processor.

I have searched high and low on the internet can can't tell either way, and can't seem to make it work on my x100 Xeon Phi.

Comment: I am struggling with this same question. No documentation anywhere though it does say it supports the Intel Xeon Phi which might be translated as all models? It doesn't help that DAAL apparently will run on the host CPU if the MIC is not available for whatever reason. Is there an equivalent of the OFFLOAD_REPORT for daal? I cannot figure out if the DAAL examples are running on the coprocessor or on the CPU.

Answer (score 1):

Okay. Found this. Only the KNL is mentioned in the list of Xeon Phi processors. It is not explicit though that the KNC is not supported.
[image]

From [Daal supports KNL](https://software.intel.com/en-us/articles/opendaal)

Comment: That would make sense.  KNL uses the same AVX512F machine code as Skylake-SP (Scalable Xeon), while KNC uses its own SIMD machine code format that's similar to but not compatible with AVX512.  So a separate build of DAAL would have been needed to work on KNC.  (And apparently there isn't one).  Or for any hand-written asm in DAAL, it would have had to be hand-ported to KNC.

Comment: Confirmation from the Intel DAAL Github page: https://github.com/intel/daal/issues/39#issuecomment-438616658